# How to forward ssh agent to running docker container?

Tags: docker, ssh-agent

I'd like to use my ssh keys inside a docker container that is already running. So far I was only able to find solutions to forward ssh keys during the build stage or run stage. But mounting the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` path when running `docker run` doesn't seem to work as the path changes when logging out.

For example, I'd like to start a new shell inside a docker container with my ssh agent forwarded.

```bash
docker exec -ti CONTAINER_ID bash
```